# React Router not rendering correct component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-component

I am a beginner in React and trying to understand routing. I have created a learning project and want to render three different components each with a different path. However, all the paths result in the display of the App component.

I've tried finding solutions on multiple sources, but not able to figure out the issue! Please have a look. Thanks in advance.

[image: Project Structure]

Root.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import ScreensList from './List';
import ScreensWeather from './Weather';
import App from '../App';

const ScreensRoot = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={App}/>
        <Route path="/list" component={ScreensList} />
        <Route path="/weather" component={ScreensWeather} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

export default ScreensRoot;
```

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
   render(){
      return (
         <div>
            Hello from App!
         </div>
      )
   }
}   

export default App;
```

List.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import List from '../components/List';

const ScreensList = () => (
    <div>
        <List/>
    </div>
);

export default ScreensList;
```

List.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

const List = (
    <div>Hello from List Component!</div>
);

export default List;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import './screens/Root';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: You aren't including Root.jsx anywhere. This is where the route switching is handled. Switch App with ScreensRoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you've defined a `ScreensRoot` component but you're not using anywhere. Assuming you want that to be the actual root of your project, then in your `index.js` you must use it instead of `App`:

```
ReactDOM.render(<ScreensRoot/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

(Note that you'll need to import `ScreensRoot` in your `index.js` in order for this to work).

Answer (score 3):

1.Insted of

```
import { Router } from 'react-router';
```

use

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
```

2.change

```
const List =  (
  <div>Hello from List Component!</div>
);
```

to

```
const List = () => (
  <div>Hello from List Component!</div>
);
```

3. As others mentioned

```
ReactDOM.render(<ScreensRoot />, rootElement);
```

[Temporary codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-not-rendering-h8v0c)